# WCF binding -wsHttpBinding uses a session?

Tags: iis, session, wcf-binding, wshttpbinding

In a [previous thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1396839/wcf-timing-out-intermittently) one of the respondents said that using wsHttpBinding used a session. Since I'm working in a clustered IIS environment, should I disable this? As far as I know, sessions don't work in a cluster.

If I need to disable this, how do I go about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That probably was me :-) By default, your service and the binding used will determine if a session comes into play or not.

If you don't do anything, and use wsHttpBinding, you'll have a session. If you want to avoid that, you should:

- switch to another protocol/binding where appropriate
- decorate your service contracts with a SessionMode attribute

If you want to stop a service from ever using a session, you can do so like this:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="....", SessionMode=SessionMode.NotAllowed)]
interface IYourSession
{
....
}
```

and you can decorate your service class with the appropriate [instance context mode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicebehaviorattribute.instancecontextmode.aspx) attributes:

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.PerCall)]
class YourService : IYourService
{
  ....
}
```

With this, you should be pretty much on the safe side and not get any sessions whatsoever.

Marc

Comment: +1 for helpful default wsHttpBinding info.  Should the interface read `interface IYourService` instead of `IYourSession`?  I was trying to link the two samples together :)  Thanks!

Comment: How is (for wshttpbinding) the relationship between SessionMode.NotAllowed and maxConcurrentSessions of serviceThrottling? Perhaps maxConcurrentSessions points to not having to validate the security context of client proxies and SessionMode.NotAllowed points to being a stateless service.